# Skip-gram model multiplicative constant in the objective function?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, natural-language, loss-functions, word2vec, language-models

I was reading this paper (https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5021-distributed-representations-of-words-and-phrases-and-their-compositionality.pdf) I cannot understand where does the multiplicative constant $1/T$ get from?

[image]

I understand that the objective function is to maximize the probability of any context words given the current center word:

[image]

When taking $\log$ there is no multiplicative constant. So, what is the clue?

Comment: Averaging the log likelihood tends to produce optima of around the same size when fitting models to datasets of substantially different sizes.  The factor of $1/T$ ruins some powerful statistical interpretations coming from likelihood theory, though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Motivation for average log-likelihood](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/267847/motivation-for-average-log-likelihood)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, the multiplicative constant 1/T can be added ad-hoc to the objective function or not, it is irrelevant.  Maximizing the objective function is equivalent to maximizing its Logarithm, and is also equivalent to maximizing its Logarithm times a constant.

For numerical optimization it can be an advantage to consider the average of the log-likelihood (by taking the average appears the 1/T factor you mention) instead of the unnormalized likelihood.    The reason for this was explained [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/267847/motivation-for-average-log-likelihood), and is related to having similar values of the log likelihood independently of the dataset size.

Comment: But what is the intuition / meaning behind adding $1/T$?

Comment: Adding the 1/T is to take the average Log-Likelihood, I have edited the answer as I was omitting some important details